# Hartl's tutorial "Couldn't find User with id=1" (chapter 7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Next newbie problem in Hartl's Tutorial. Now in chapter 7. . While I'm running App I'm getting something like this in my browser:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

Couldn't find User with id=1

Rails.root: C:/rails_project/my_app
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:4:in `show'

Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"1"}

Show session dump

Show env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

My user_controller.rb looks like this:

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController

     def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    describe "profile page" do  
    #Code to make a user variable
    before { visit user_path(user) }

        it { should have_selector('h1',    :text => user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('title', :text => user.name) }
    end
  end


  def new
  end


  end
```

Thanks for help & intrest!

Comment: Are you sure you have users in your DB?

Comment: Call me lame, but how can I check this?

Comment: Try this: http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/  and take a look at what is in your sqlite DB

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but did you put your test code in with your controller code? I've always understood that the test code goes in a separate file.

Comment: You're right, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Have you checked whether you have users or not yet? An alternative way to do this could be to go into the command line and type `rails c --sandbox` followed by `User.find(1)`

Comment: Ok. I've checked this. And something strange appeared. It did't found any user and when I'am trying to create new with "user = User.new(name:"blabla" , email: "blabla@bla.com" )" I'am getting user with no user id ( user Id = nil). When I'am trying to save it I'am getting false". Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I've found the solution. The key was to create new db (probably I've reseted db, not easy to be newbie!). Thx for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_by_id` instead of `find`.

`find` results in an error when the parameter doesn't exists in the model.

See also: [difference between find, where and find_by_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185919/difference-between-find-where-and-find-by-id)