# What's the difference between find, where and find_by_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What's the difference between `find`, `where` and `find_by_id`?  They all work when you try to find a user given an ID.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The difference is what they return when a record is found, or when it's not found.  Consider the following examples:

```
>> User.create name: 'THE USER' # creates a user with id = 1
>> User.find(1) # returns the user
>> User.find_by_id(1) # returns the user
>> User.where(id: 1).first # returns the user
```

As you can see, an existing user can be fetched using any of the 3 methods.  The big difference with using `where` is you can chain commands (of course, without calling `first` first.)

Let's have a look at when you try to find a record that isn't existing

```
>> User.find(2) # raises an exception
>> User.find_by_id(2) # nil
>> User.where(id: 2).first # nil
```

So here, it's obvious that when you use `find` to search for a record that isn't existing, you get an exception.  That exception is `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` which renders a 404 on production environment.

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

Rails 4 uses the following syntax for `find_by`

```
>> User.find_by(id: 1)  # returns nil if there's no user with an id of 1
>> User.find_by!(id: 1) # raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound when no record is found
```

Comment: You should note that all `find_by_*` methods are deprecrated in rails 4 in favor of `find_by(*: ...)` so here that would be be : `find_by(id: ...)`

Comment: wow I didn't know that. thanks! why isn't that mentioned here? http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html

Comment: @pjam 
All dynamic methods except for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated.
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations

Answer (score 5):

**find** => This return single record if the given primary_key(id) exists in the system otherwise in will give an error.

```
Model.find(required_id_value)
```

**find_by** => This will return single record depends on the given attribute, and if the value of the attribute is not exist in the DB it will return nil.

```
Model.find_by_name("your name")
```

name here is the attribute and it must be exist in your Modal.

**where** => This will return an active record relation with zero or more records you need to use first to return only one record or nil in case zero records return.

```
Model.where(id: id_value).first
```

Comment: **Record.find(0)** raises `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Record with 'id'=0`

**Record.find_by(id: 0)** returns `nil`
Record.find_by_id(0) also returns nil although it is deprecated in later versions of rails.


**Record.where(id: 0)** returns an empty array

Answer (score 1):

`find` => this is used to find row by `id`. This will return single record.

```
YourModel.find(2)
Address.find(1)
```

`find_by` => this is used to get row by any attributes of record. This will return first matching record if condition matches.

```
YourModel.find_by_attrname("value")
Address.find_by_street_name_and_city("Andheri", "Newyork")
Addess.find_by_id(4)
```

`where` => this is used get active records based on conditions to return active record relation (i.e.) may be zero or more records.

```
YourModel.where(:attrname => "something")
Address.where(:city => "Newyork")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple to me....

'Find' returns single object to you as a result but 'Where' returns Array to you so you need to add .each to fetch each object from that array.

Answer (score 0):

Not big deal, but there is another difference between `find` and `where` when you try to retrieve 1+ records and then you need to update each record and you want to use the `find_each`, it gonna work over the `where` method because the result of the `where` query is a `ActiveRecord::Relation`. But if you try to use `find_each` over the result with the find, you gonna have an error.

```rb
Profile.find([1, 2, 3]).find_each { |e| puts e.id }
=> NoMethodError (undefined method `find_each' for 
 <Array:0x0000555e923d3f38>)


Profile.where(id: [1, 2, 3]).find_each { |e| puts e.id }
=> 1
=> 2
=> 3
```