# What is the difference between find and find_by?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know from the rails documentation that `find` will result in a `RecordNotFound` error. However, the `find_by` method simply returns `nil` if a record is not found. Returning `nil` seems more intuitive to me and safe in general, so I am wondering if there is any benefit in using the `find` method over the `find_by` method?

For example, what is the difference between the following:

```
myRecord.find(1)
```

and

```
myRecord.find_by(id: 1)
```

If the only difference is that `find` raises an error when a record isn't found, I don't really see the benefit in using `find`.

### EDIT

For all the people that jumped on my question and said that it had been already answered, you are wrong. I clearly stated that I knew `find` returns an error when a record is not found (which is what everyone else emphasizes in their answers) and that `find_by` returns nil. I want to know if there are any other differences.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185919/whats-the-difference-between-find-where-and-find-by-id possible duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between find, where and find\_by\_id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185919/whats-the-difference-between-find-where-and-find-by-id)

Comment: I apologize for my comment. I'm glad you found a satisfactory answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your specific example there is little difference between the two of them other than the **error** vs **nil** which you mention. Whether you want to handle an **error** or **nil** is totally up to you.

For a great explanation of understanding when an **error** is preferable to **nil** and vice versa read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966430/rails-2-model-find1-gives-activerecord-error-when-id-1-does-not-exist/4966553#4966553).

If you are searching by an attribute other than **id** using **find** will not work as it can only access elements by their **id**.

Comment: Thank you for linking to that SO question. DHH has a really good explanation as you said he did. Everyone else who commented on my question clearly didn't understand the intent of my question. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. You can also see the source code through the documentation if you want to get into the implementation differences between the two. https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class . Scroll down and click on "show source"